# How to allow Select to also enter Edit mode in a Datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Question says it all. I basically need to allow users to click Select in a Datagrid and it enters the the edit row mode instead of the user having to click select and then edit? The reason I need for selection to be done first is because I am passing some values to the database in the code behind. Right now, as I said, the user clicks Select, then Edit, then marks a checkbox that is needed, and then update. I want to cut this process to Select, mark the checkbox, and update. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort of depends (slightly) on what event you're currently handling.

In your `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you can just do this:

```
yourGridView.EditIndex = yourGridView.SelectedIndex;
```

If you're in the `SelectedIndexChanging` event, you need to do this:

```
yourGridView.EditIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
```

Where "e" is your `GridViewSelectEventArgs` object.

Depending on how your code is structured, you may need to call `yourGridView.DataBind();` after setting the EditIndex.

Comment: Well that was way simpler than I thought. Thanks Jadarnel!